# Find the integral $\int \frac{11x-18}{x^{11} \sqrt[6]{x^{12}-2x+3}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{11x-18}{x^{11} \sqrt[6]{x^{12}-2x+3}}dx$$

I am trying to solve using $$x^{12}-2x+3=t \implies  (12x^{11}-2)dx=dt$$

I am facing the problems, can anyone help me?

Comment: @ SmarthBansal..what is maximum method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint**:  Just take $x^{12}$ out from radical, Denominator becomes $x^{13} {\sqrt[6]{1+\cfrac{-2}{x^{11}}+\cfrac{3}{x^{12}}}}$:

$$\int \cfrac{\cfrac{11}{x^{12}} - \cfrac{18}{x^{13}}}{\sqrt[6]{1+\cfrac{-2}{x^{11}}+\cfrac{3}{x^{12}}}}$$

Comment: good observation! Problem seems to be specifically made to be solved in this manner.

Comment: @Kumar Ayush..........super observation....

Comment: @KingTut yeah i also think so